# How to run Linux on a custom PCB

Tags: firmware

If I could design a PCB, with all PC ics (e.g. ARM CPU, DDR3, flash nand, etc). How to tell Linux about devices connected to it? In other words, how to deal with devices connected to the CPU from a Linux app?

Comment: Read up on Flattened Device Trees (FTDs) and boot loaders like u-boot, but your question is really far too broad to get a good answer.

Comment: @TypeIA Sorry, isn't linux having built-in drivers? Should not it be able to automatically discover all connected devices? Sorry that question is too broad but I don't know what to study

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow you should not be using two different accounts for asking and commenting on your own question. You generally should not have two accounts! No big deal, though, if you want, that can be fixed!

Comment: You're mixing all kinds of levels (hardware, drivers, application software) up. You first needs to learn some basics like computer architecture. A user application doesn't need to know about DDR3 RAM for example, an application just wants memory. So there are many separations in place. If you want to learn all this, study information technology. You might need **a couple of years** for that. If you just want to write an application, just follow some tutorial.

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow - Hi, As commented above, you should not be using multiple accounts on the same question (assuming that you are the same person who asked the question). While use of multiple accounts is allowed, *they must not interact in any way* (asking/answering, commenting, voting) and *you must not do anything with two accounts, that you could not do with just one account*. Some people find it difficult to stay within these rules, and we regularly delete accounts which break these rules. You can ask SE to [merge the accounts](/help/merging-accounts), if you want to avoid future problems.

Comment: @SamGibson please delete the question.

Comment: Technically, you are asking us how to build something like Beaglebone or Pi. Engineers learnt and researched years for that.

Answer (score 5):

If you want all the functionality of a PC on one board, it already exists and runs a Linux OS. Look up a "Raspberry Pi Zero" or even a full "Raspberry Pi 4".  Each is available up to 8GB RAM. Other systems like BeagleBone Black can be used.  No reason to reinvent the wheel.

These systems have huge development communities supporting all aspects of the system.  Price of a Raspberry Pi Zero will be a fraction of what you could build one yourself - and no effort for design or software development.

Size of a "Raspberry Pi Zero W" is about 80mm x 25mm on a Single PCB.

If that doesn't work, you need to clarify your goal. If your goal is, "because I'd like to do it myself", you'll need to figure out how to surround yourself with a community of developers to help you out.  This is not a one-person project.

Good luck.

Comment: This is just a part recommendation.

Comment: @TonyM I think the important part is the first sentence and the last paragraph.

Comment: but I think Raspberry drivers are non-open-source in-binary format (or some of them), so how to work on that in an alternative way to develop other boatloader?

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow Drivers and bootloaders are different things. If there was an "alternative way" to make them open source then quite possibly, those open source drivers would exist already. To write open source drivers, all information about the hardware devices is needed. Not all manufacturers (want to) provide such information. Making your own board might be possible with only open-source driver devices but as mentioned, that is generally not a one-man job. And if for you it was, you would be designing it already.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks, what If i bought a manufacturer device? Will they provide me with binaries to link it with my build anyway? Does these drivers cost extra cost in addtion to the IC itself?

Comment: Your external devices will usually connect via serial communication protocols (I2C or SPI ).  You'll need to wire it up, write some Python or C code (or copy code written by a device vendor). Some more specifics of what kind of device would be helpful.  Please add details to your question , not in these comments.